# How can I escape this character ► to be shown correctly on ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, escape

When I test an email with the character `►` using other methods it works ok, but after sending through ExactTarget it gets rendered incorrectly by the most part of mobile email clients.

How can I encode or escape this character so it renders properly?

Comment: Have you checked the encoding/'target language' settings on your email?  What charset do you have in your meta tags for the email? Are you using the character in the HTML, or the HTML entity (&#9654;)?

Comment: Yeah, this works! 
Thanks.